# How to "rebuild" a decayed **char?

Tags: c, void-pointers

The following code is a simplified version of my larger program to demonstrate the problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

const int m = 5;
char **words1;
char **words2;

void f(void *v) {
    printf("v: %p\n", v);

    int len = v==words1 ? 3 : 4;
    printf("len: %d\n", len);

    for (int i=0; i<m; i++) {
        // What goes here?
        /*
        char *c = malloc(sizeof(char) * len);
        c = (char*)v; // Something _like_ this?!
        printf("%s\n", c);
        */
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    words1 = malloc(m * sizeof(char*));
    printf("%p\n", words1);
    words2 = malloc(m * sizeof(char*));
    printf("%p\n", words2);

    for (int i=0; i<m; i++) {
        words1[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 3);
        words2[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 4);
        strcpy(words1[i], "22");
        strcpy(words2[i], "333");
    }

    f(words1);
    f(words2);

    for (int i=0; i<m; i++) {
        free(words1[i]);
        free(words2[i]);
    }
    free(words1);
    free(words2);
}
```

I have two global `**char` which I *think* are on the heap (because `malloc`).

The signature of `f()` cannot change, i.e. it can only accept `void *`.

Importantly, in the real program the data in the `**char` is too big for the stack.

In short: how do I get the `**char` back from the `*void`?

Comment: Firstly, why are those variables global? But specifically for your question you can just assign it: `char **s = v;`

Comment: `c = malloc(sizeof(char) * len); c = (char*)v;` Note that that doesn't make sense and thus is unclear as an example of what you are wanting to do. Because it makes no sense to `malloc` something and then immediately overwrite/throw it away on the next line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply assign it to the right type back in `f()`:

```
   char **f_words = v;
    for (int i=0; i<m; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", f_words[i]);
    }
```

Also, your way of identifying the length of words in `f()` isn't good.

You can either pass the length as an additional argument to `f()` or you could terminate the words list with `NULL` pointer.

Comment: Thanks! I've also seen `char **f_words = (char **)v;` - is that the same, just "nicer" to the reader?

Comment: @Bridgey A void pointer (`void*`) is assignment compatible with any other data pointer. So the cast is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Consider passing following `struct` to `f()`. It will make obtaining `len` ,`m` and `words` much cleaner and with no global variables.

```
struct S {
  int len;
  int m;
  char **words;
};

void f(void *v) {
  struct S *s = v;
  int len = s->len;
  int m = s->m;
  char **word = s->words;
  
  printf("v: %p\n", v);
  printf("len: %d\n", len);
  for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
       printf("%s\n", words[i]);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   ...
   // passing a pointer to compound literal
   f(&(struct S){ 3, m, words1});
   f(&(struct S){ 4, m, words2});
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I've accepted P.P's answer because it was the first and most direct to my specific question, but your answer is definitely something I will implement in the future. Thanks!